# Go big int literal overflows int64

Tags: go, primes

Is there a way to assign a humongous integer literal to a big Int in Go?

```
// error: constant overflows int64
var a = big.NewInt(20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921)
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't take a string representation?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, duh.

```
a.SetString("20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921", 10)
```